# How does linked tables work in Access front end, SQL backend?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

As per my understanding all tables have a list of pointers that shows where the data is located. In the case of split database the database pointers are used to retrieve the tables before a query is ran.

Is it the same case with SQL Server? If not what differences are there in the process of data retrieval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How this works is really much the same.

The only major difference is:

When hitting a SQL server back end table, then ONLY records meeting your criteria are pulled from the server over the network connection.

When hitting a Access “file” back end, then ONLY records meeting your criteria are pulled from the file over the network connection – however, this “limited” pulling of records over the network ONLY occurs if an index is available and can be used. If an index cannot be used (or there is not one) then the local database engine (JET or ACE) will pull the whole table down the network pipe.

So in some cases if the query criteria cannot use an index (or there is no index), then a full table scan occurs and thus the whole table will be pulled over the network down to the access client.

So not in all cases does the whole table get pulled down the client.

In the case of sql server, if an index cannot be used (or there is not one), then a full table scan will occur. However this full table scan occurs server side and thus no network traffic occurs during this table scan. So even without an index, or with an index, ONLY records meeting your criteria are pulled down the network pipe to the local client. The SQL server hard drive might go crazy or spin hard without an index, but no network traffic occurs during this process.

Contrary to popular belief, even with a “file” based back end (no SQL server, but just a plane Jane access file sitting on a shared folder on that server), then Access will only pull records meeting the criteria down the network pipe. However this optimizing only occurs if Access can use an index for the criteria.

So if you have 500,000 invoices in a table, and use:

Select * from tblInvoices where InvoiceNumber = 12336

If you have an index on the InvoiceNumber column, then even without any kind of server, Access will only pull the one row. This is the case for SQL server, or Access.

The significant difference is that if you don’t have an index with SQL server, then network traffic will still only be the one record transferred down the network pipe to the client. However without an index on SQL server, the hard drive and SQL server will work very hard and do a full table scan.

As noted with Access back end (file), if no index is available, then both a full table scan will occur, and ALL records will come down the network pipe to the client.

What this means is that SQL server is far more forgiving of “poor” designs, or of queries that don’t have an index, or queries that cannot use an index.

So for an Access back end, then there is a greater chance that the whole table will be sent down the network pipe – especially in the case where an index cannot be used, or an index cannot be used for the given criteria.

Of course how updates occur is a different matter and different question. Your question was limited to data retrieval.

edit:
Read the following article of mine on networks and Access:

http://www.kallal.ca/Wan/Wans.html

Comment: So the entire file is pulled weather the linked table is Access Backend or SQL Backend if there are no indexes? But in SQL Server there is an option to write a pass through query which is faster when there are no indexes?  

The reason I am confused on this is that there are many tutorials in SQL migration which tries to use a pass through query but from your reply it seems like there would be no difference in the Access linked tables and SQL Server linked tables if we consider the initial speed as they are both pulling all the data over server or network connection.

Comment: Also is the same case with non split Access database or is it faster than the split database?

Comment: No, in fact I clear stated that the whole table is NOT pulled in both cases. The only case the whole table is pulled is when you are using a file based back end and no index can be used.  So the file is not pulled and I gave a query example with 500,000 rows of data in a standard file back end. Only the ONE record will be pulled in that case - even with a file based back end.

Comment: And no, the entire file is not pulled. Again: if no index, then for a file based back end, the whole table (not the file - the table) is pulled. For sql server with no index, then only rows matching the criteria come down the network pipe.  For both sql sever and file based if a index can be used, then in BOTH cases ONLY the records meeting the criteria are pulled down the network pipe. So if you have a index then the whole table is not pulled. So no access does not pull the whole table when doing a query - even with a file based back end this does not occur if a index is available.

Comment: and for any of the above to occur you do NOT need to use a pass-though query. A PT query on a single table to grab on record is NOT faster then grabbing one record with a linked table and a regular query.

Comment: Now if the PT query is complex or involves multiple tables, then a PT query will be better. So have to distinguish the type of query. A query on one table not going to benefit by a pt query. On multiple tables with complex joins, then yes - but that is a massive different issue then a query on one table.

Comment: And split vs non split? No difference. The issue is if you split and place the back end half way across the country on a different server. It not the issue of splitting - run speed is about the same for split vs non split - but splitting over a network or a wan is a VERY different issue.

Comment: I just added a link for you to read at the end of my post - read it, and then read it again - it will answer most your questions. What I stated is dead 100% crystal clear - the file and table is not pulled down the network unless it has to be.

Comment: You are awesome! I saw that you have a few blogs before 2014 which I am going to read as well. Do you have any new content on Access and SQL Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184941/discussion-between-namko-and-albert-d-kallal).

Comment: Been meaning to update some things in regards to sql server, but what I have is 13 or more years old - and what is stated still 100% applies now.